Transistor using base voltage without collector
I have been trying to make logic gates from transistors. Their collector-emitter parts are connected in series and a LED (with a limiting resistor in series) is inserted in the emitter of the end-point transistor. However I cannot as I noticed that the transistor would power the LED even without collector being powered (because some of the other transistors in the string is cut off). Why is this happening?
I am using 3.3 V power supply and 58050 transistor.

Please show a schematic of what you are attempting.

Do you want to make logic gates that can be connected together into complex systems? Or is this just for a simple demonstration of single gates that won't be part of a larger system? Also, I suspect you mean S8050.

Need a circuit diagram @billy bob joe. Use the Circuit Lab editor in the question toolbar.

You can use the Falstad circuit sim (https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html) to try out your ideas (and you can share a schematic from it, too.) There's examples of gates made from transistors.

And, it may very well be that your transistor is miswired. Check the S8050 data sheet here: https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ss8050-d.pdf

A logic gate does not have an LED in it.  Please post your schematic.  This site has a schematic editor, but a cocktail napkin shot with a cell phone is good enough.  Be sure to include a unique reference designator (Q1, R3, etc.) for each component, so we can discuss them without confusion.

@billy bob joe, I have edited your question to make it clearer. Please, verify it and write a comment.


the transistor would power the LED even without collector being powered

That's because the base-emitter junction is still a semiconductor junction. Just like a diode!

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
So you're just powering the LED via the base.
There's a big difference between having the collector connected vs left open:

simulate this circuit
LEFT: When the collector is powered, the transistor is in the active region - is just an emitter follower, and the input (base) current is small - in the simulation above it is about 0.02mA. The LED is mostly powered from 5V via the collector.
RIGHT: With the collector left open, the transistor is in the deep saturation, and its B-E diode is in series with the LED, and the LED is powered from the input. The input current and the LED current are the same.

Nice explanation... but nasty devices are those BJTs with their non-linear input... I stand and look at your schematics and mine, and wonder which is better - standalone or combined with resistor meters. Each has its advantages and disadvantages, but in both cases the meters are too many. On the one hand, it's good because they create a sense of reality; on the other hand, they clutter schematics. In my hand-drawn schematics, I used voltage bars to visualize voltage magnitudes and current loops to visualize current paths.

Turning a disadvantage into an advantage
It is not a good idea in a digital circuit (logic gate) where the transistors are supposed to work as switches to connect the load to the emitter because it results in an analog circuit where the transistors work in active mode (semi-conductive). This is the so-called "common-collector" configuration, or better said, an emitter follower. But you did it anyway and noticed this undesired (in this case) effect; so let's use it for something useful - to explain in another way this famous circuit.
Basic idea
From this viewpoint, you can think of this configuration as a "helped input voltage source". Let's see why by following the evolution of this idea through a step-by-step scenario. To grasp the idea, it is better to use equivalent electric circuits.
Reinventing the emitter follower in another way
Weak input voltage source unloaded
Imagine we have an imperfect (week) voltage source with a high internal resistance Rin = 9 kΩ that produces 5 V (you can think of it as a perfect voltage source V with a 9 kΩ resistor in series). It is weak but unloaded - only a perfect 1 GΩ voltmeter is connected to it. So there is no voltage drop across Rin (no loss), and the full 5 V input voltage appears across the "load".

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Weak input source loaded
But if we connect the weak 9 kΩ source to the strong 1kΩ load, a significant current is drawn from it by the load (to monitor the current without cluttering the schematic, we can replace the 1 kΩ load resistor with an ammeter with the same internal resistance). The load current "creates" a significant voltage drop VRin = IL.Rin across Rin. Rin and RL form a voltage divider.

simulate this circuit
If we sweep V, we will see that only 1/10 of it is applied to the load.

Weak input source supplemented
What do we do in life when someone is weak? We help them. Then let's connect another voltage source in parallel to the weak input source. It has to be variable; so we connect a variable resistor Rce in series and begin adjusting the voltage across the load (like above, to monitor the voltage without cluttering the schematic, we can replace the 1 kΩ load resistor with a voltmeter with the same internal resistance). Our goal is to make it equal to Vin; so we connect an ammeter as a null indicator between the weak input source and the load.

simulate this circuit
As you can see from the ammeter reading, there is no any current drawn from the input sources; it is completely assisted. All the current through the load is provided by Vcc.
Emitter follower
The transistor Q in an emitter follower does exactly the same - it adjusts its collector-emitter "resistance" so that to make VL = Vin, but because it is not perfect (Vbe is not zero) it does not make it precise.

simulate this circuit
Let's now sweep (change) the input voltage of the perfect input voltage source V from 0 V to 10 V to see Vin and VL.

Simulated emitter follower
Now we are going to do a clever trick with CircuitLab - we are going to take the present values of the voltages and currents, and calculate the present resistances. Then we replace the transistor with two resistors Rbe and Rce representing its two junctions (of course, this is only for the purposes of intuitive understanding); hence these "ugly" not easy to remember resistor values. I repeat it - these resistor values are static; they represent only the current transistor state.

simulate this circuit
Now, the powerful voltage source Vcc is connected through the collector-emitter part in parallel to the load, and helps the weak input source.
Disconnected Vcc
Now imagine the collector is not connected to Vcc. Like in Schematic 1.2 above, the weak input source is directly connected (through the base-emitter junction) to the load, and a significant current is drawn from it by the load (as above, Rin and RL form a voltage divider). It "creates" a significant voltage drop VRin = IL.Rin across Rin.

simulate this circuit
As a result, less than 1/10 of V is applied to the load.

Conclusions
So in an emitter follower, two voltage sources - weak and powerful, are connected in parallel to the common load. Or, an emitter follower can be considered as a "helped input voltage source"; hence the expression Ie = Ib + Ic.
We can draw a conclusion that in the common-emitter stage, the output collector current is only an amplified base current (Ic = β.Ib) while in the common-collector stage, the output emitter current is a sum of the amplified and base current - Ie = β.Ib + Ib.
It is interesting that this "harmful" effect can be used for something useful. For example, in the 90s, I used it to make a simple backup supply (see my paper).
Summary
It is created by Gemini AI keeping the summary a bit more informal:
This article explains how an emitter follower circuit, something that's usually not ideal in digital circuits, can actually be a big help.
Think of it like this: you have a weak battery that can't quite power your device by itself. The emitter follower acts like a friend who jumps in to lend a hand. The circuit uses a stronger power source to take over some of the work, making sure your device gets the juice it needs.
The secret is that the emitter follower combines the weak battery (the original voltage source) with a stronger one (the collector supply) to act like two power sources working together. This is like your friend helping you push something heavy - together you can do the job!
In the end, the emitter follower takes something that might seem like a problem (a weak power source) and turns it into a solution by giving it a boost. Pretty cool, right?
